# Sum a homogeneous List<object>

Tags: c#, list, sum, type-conversion, numbers

I am working on a C# application. I have multiple lists of objects i.e. each list contains values of different types like double, int etc stored in the form of object in the list. Each list contains the same type of objects.

```
List<object> l1 = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

List<object> l2 = {1.1, 2.1, 3.2, 4.2, 5.6, 6.1, 7.5, 8.6, 9.2};
```

There can be many other lists of different types stored in the form of object. My issue is that i have to recognize the type of the object of the list from first value and add all the elements of the list. I am using the following code to get the type .

```
Type typeOfCurrentField = l1[0].GetType();
```

This gives me the type of the object. Now i have to get all the values of the list converted to this type. Currently, i am trying this:

```
dynamic sum = null;
Type typeOfCurrentField = null;
for(int i = 0; i < l1.Count; i++)
{
    if (typeOfCurrentField == null)
    {
        typeOfCurrentField = l1[i].GetType();
        sum = Convert.ChangeType(l1[i], typeOfCurrentField);
    }
    else
    {
        sum = sum + Convert.ChangeType(l1[i], typeOfCurrentField);;
    }
    
}
```

This gives me the following exception:

```
Operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'object' Exception of type ==> Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException
```

How can i overcome this problem ?

Comment: Are storing always numeric value? All items in the list will have the same type?

Comment: yes, values will be numeric and a single list will have all the values of same type @dbvega

Comment: In this case you dont need to check the type to compute the sum. I will post an answer, check it out.

Comment: Eww don't use dynamic if you can avoid it. You could use reflection to dynamically invoke Enumerable.Cast<> followed by Enumerable.Sum but you'll still end up with a result of static type object you'd have to cast to something. Alternatively check out Jon Skeets [generic operators](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/miscutil/usage/genericoperators.html) But you'd still need reflection and `MakeGenericMethod`

Answer (score 4):

```cs
dynamic sum = 0;
foreach (var v in l1.Cast<dynamic>())
  sum += v;
```

Comment: This cause an exception for `var list = new List<object> { 1, 2.1f, 3.2d, 4.2m };`.

Comment: @OlivierRogier I asked and the user confirmed all items in the list will be the same type. Check questions on the top.

Comment: Ok. Indeed, I have not saw the comment... So the OP miswrote his question that is thus trivial : "**I have multiple lists of objects i.e. each list contains values of different types like double, int etc stored in the form of object in the list.**"

Comment: Little variation: `l1.Cast<dynamic>().ToList().ForEach(v => sum += v);`

Comment: @OlivierRogier I wanted to write it clear.. Here is a another `l1.Cast<dynamic>().Aggregate((a, b) => a + b);`

Comment: And it is faster with aggregate ! 23459ms instead of 26622ms for a loop of 100000000.

Comment: I am willing to bet its faster with straight reflection. There are so many implications to using dynamic. It has to spin up the DLR that's a huge hit /shrug

Comment: @dbvega can you please explain what will .Cast<dynamic> do here ?

Comment: @Waleed Naveed in this case dynamic tell compiler that variable’s type is unknown until runtime.

Comment: @dbvega i assume that with your code i don't have to do "Type typeOfCurrentField = l1[0].GetType();" . . . Your code will work fine standalone. ?